# TypeError: findFaces() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vid'

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe

I have been watching this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01sAkU_NvOY&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org

For the hand module it went fine but for the pose and face module I have been getting error at the same position I have gone through the code and I dont see where I have made a mistake.

```
import cv2 as cv
import mediapipe as mp
import time

class FaceDetector():
    def __init__(self, minDetectionCon=0.5):
        self.minDetectionCon = minDetectionCon
        self.mpFD = mp.solutions.face_detection
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
        self.faceDetection = self.mpFD.FaceDetection()

    def findFaces(self, vid, draw=True):
        vidRBG = cv.cvtColor(vid, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.faceDetection.process(vidRBG)
        #print(results)
        bboxs = []
        if self.results.detections:
            for id, detection in enumerate(self.results.detections):
                bboxc = detection.location_data.relative_bounding_box
                ih, iw, ic = vid.shape
                bbox = int(bboxc.xmin * iw), int(bboxc.ymin * ih), \
                       int(bboxc.width * iw), int(bboxc.height * ih)
                bboxs.append([bbox, detection.score])
                cv.rectangle(vid, bbox, (255, 0, 255), 2)
                cv.putText(vid, f'{int(detection.score[0]*100)}%',
                           (bbox[0], bbox[1]-20), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        return vid, bboxs

def main():
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
    pTime = 0
    detector = FaceDetector
    while True:
        suc, vid = cap.read()
        vid, bboxs = detector.findFaces(vid)#getting error here
        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime
        cv.putText(vid, f'FPS:{int(fps)}', (20, 70), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        cv.imshow("VIDEO", vid)
        if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
```

For both the pose estimation module and face detection module both the  errors are occurring in the same line.

Error I keep receiving

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\PROJECTS\Face Detection\face_detection_module.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "S:\PROJECTS\Face Detection\face_detection_module.py", line 55, in main
    vid = detector.findFaces(vid)
TypeError: findFaces() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vid'
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sn_xpupm\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Comment: `detector = FaceDetector` -- seems like you forgot to actually call the constructor...

Comment: I did put that its right above while True

Comment: Yes, that is the line I'm referring to. I don't see a `()` following the class name there, do you?

Answer (score 0):

As FaceDetector() is a class and to make detector as an instance of this class. Change as follows.

```
detector = FaceDetector()
```